# How to get single value from List<E> in android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-sqlite

I want to get a value of single column returned in the form of `ArrayList<>` from `SQLite` for retrieving data my code is :

```
    public List<ContentDataObject> findAll() {
    List<ContentDataObject> contentDataObjects = new ArrayList<ContentDataObject>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT " +
            DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_FULLTEXT+ 
            " FROM " + DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_TABLE_NAME;
    database = dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    try {
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        Log.i(TAG, "Returned " + cursor.getCount() + " rows");

        if(cursor != null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                ContentDataObject contentDataObject = check(cursor);
                contentDataObjects.add(contentDataObject);
                cursor.moveToNext();                    
            }
            // Make sure to close the cursor
            cursor.close();
        }           
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return contentDataObjects;
}
```

my `check(cursor)` is :

```
public ContentDataObject check(Cursor cursor) {

    ContentDataObject contentDataObject = new ContentDataObject();

    contentDataObject.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_ID)));
    contentDataObject.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_TITLE)));
    contentDataObject.setFulltext(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_FULLTEXT)));
    contentDataObject.setState(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_STATE)));
    contentDataObject.setNewValue(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_NEW)));
    contentDataObject.setHeader(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_HEADER)));
    contentDataObject.setColor(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_COLOR)));
    contentDataObject.setNext(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_NEXT)));
    contentDataObject.setPrevious(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_PREVIOUS)));

    return contentDataObject;

}
```

in `MainActivity.java` I'm using this code :

```
ContentDataObject contentDataObject;
TextView textView;

ContentsDataSource dataSource;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myView);

    dataSource = new ContentsDataSource(this);
    dataSource.open();

    List<ContentDataObject> contentDataObjects = dataSource.findAll();

    textView.setText(""+contentDataObjects.indexOf(contentDataObject.getFulltext()));
}
```

but,  I'm unable to get data and set to `textView`.

Comment: Where is the initialization of `contentDataObject` in the activity ?

Comment: -1 for unclear what doesn't work nor what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't use `List<E>` if you only want to get one value from `SQLite` so you should try this one !

change `findAll()` in this way :

```
public String findAll() {
       ^^^^^^   
    String myQuery = "SELECT " +
            DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_FULLTEXT+ 
            " FROM " + DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_TABLE_NAME+
            " WHERE _id = 2";

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(myQuery, null);
    String fullText = null;
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    if(cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
        Log.w(TAG, "There is no data to display");
    }
    else {
        fullText = "";

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                fullText += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_FULLTEXT)) + "\n";
            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }// end if          
    }

    return fullText;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     
}
```

And in `onCreate()` use this :

```
ContentsDataSource dataSource;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myView);

    dataSource = new ContentsDataSource(this);
    dataSource.open();

    parseAndIsertData();

    textView.setText(dataSource.getFullText());
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

I hope this Will work for you!

Comment: Thumbs up Dear! this was what I wanted to do. Thanks  a lot.

Answer (score 0):

your contentDataObject  is never initialized so your calling actually.

```
 textView.setText(""+contentDataObjects.indexOf( NULL ));
```

Comment: I have Initialized my `contentDataObject` now but still I'm getting result `-1`!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29 indexOf returns -1 if there is no match. As you can read in my url is that you compare a OBJECT and not a string. So you should use in your code (i think): textView.setText(""+contentDataObjects.indexOf(contentDataObject)); This will return the index of the object.I don't know what you want to display in your text view, if it is the fulltext it is:contentDataObjects.get(indexOf(contentDataObject)).getFulltext()